# ZF: Url View Helper Acting Strangely

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I have the following route defined:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'users/:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'profile',
        'id' => ''
    )
);
```

When I am on the page via the shortened URL (localhost/users/someuser), the URLs defined in the layout file all link to "localhost/users". Here is the code in the layout:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index'), null, true); ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'search'), null, true); ?>">Search</a></li>
<!-- etc. -->
```

How can I fix the code so that the links in the layout file point to the correct URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the route you want to use when calling the helper, as otherwise it will use the current route, which is your `users/:id` one. I'm assuming in the case of the two examples you give, it would be `'default'`. Try replacing `null` in the the helper call with it.